# PyQt Event when a variable value is changed

Tags: python, variables, events, pyqt4, signals-slots

I have a variable t

t = 0

I want to start an event whenever t value is changed.
How ? There's no valuechanged.connect properties or anything for variables...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a global variable, this is not possible using assignment alone. But for an attribute it is quite simple: just use a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (or maybe [`__getattr__/__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)). This effectively turns assignment into a function call, allowing you to add whatever additional behaviour you like:

```
class Foo(QWidget):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self._t = 0

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t

    @t.setter
    def t(self, value):
        self._t = value
        self.valueChanged.emit(value)
```

Now you can do `foo = Foo(); foo.t = 5` and the signal will be emitted after the value has changed.

Comment: Any suggestions on the modification of your answer where I use a list. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61695982/8928024