# How to apply PyQt5 Event on a list with values instead of single variable value?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Based on SO question and answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867522/8928024) I modified the answer where the value becomes a list. It throws me an error.

Is it possible that the value is in fact a list with values? Like `value=[1,2,3]`? In this case the list represents a tabWidget index positions at three levels in the GUI... Or is this handled differently? All/Other suggestions are welcome.

Traceback error:

> ```
> createAction
>     self.tabindex.valueChanged.connect(self.do_something)
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'valueChanged'
> ```

The code:

```py
class Foo(QWidget):

    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self._t = [1,2,3]

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t

    @t.setter
    def t(self, list):
        self._t = list
        self.valueChanged.emit(list)

    def createAction(self):
        self.t.valueChanged.connect(self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        ...
        print('show something here')
```

Comment: `valueChanged` is a signal of `Foo` itself, so you should do `self.valueChanged.connect(self.do_something)`. The value that should be emitted with the signal is determined when the signal is emitted, not when connecting the signal to a slot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your solution fixed it. If you can post it as answer I can rep-wise reward it and it clears it from the unsolved question list ;-)

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueChanged` is a signal of `Foo` itself, so you should use `self.valueChanged.connect(self.do_something)` instead of `self.t.valueChanged.connect(self.do_something)`. After all, the value that should be emitted with the signal is determined when the signal is emitted, not when connecting the signal to a slot.